# Enable dynamic compression in app within GBPS LAN?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, http-compression

I have a LAN of 1000 clients with speeds of 1 GBPS.

One application hosted in IIS 7.5.

Fact: A megabyte response is transferred between the server and the client in no more than 30 miliseconds. The connection is very fast.

Fact: Some clients have older PCs (windows xp, ie7, pentium4).

I think that dynamic compression is not needed in this case, becuase the problem is not the bandwidth but the clients computer performance.

Do you recommend to disable compression?

My pages have too much javascript. In every post I refresh the page with javascript, ajax and json. In some cases when  the HTML is too big, the browser gets a little bit unresponsible. I think that compression is causing this problem.

any comments?

Answer (score 1):

A useful scenario for compression is when you have to pay for the bandwith and would like to speed up the download of large pages, but this creates a bit of work for the client having to uncompress the data before serving it.

**Turn it off.**
*You don't need it for serving pages over a high-speed LAN.*

Answer (score 0):

Definitely don't think you need the compression. But you are shooting in the dark here -- get yourself a http debugger such as the one included in google chrome and see what parts of the pages are slow.